# Replace single quote with double quote in a string python

Tags: python, string

I have a string like this:

```
char = 'TEST'
```

I am trying to end up with this result:

```
char = "'TEST'"
```

It is important that the double quotes are around the single quotes, and not the other way around.
I am using a Python connector to snowflake, and the latter is the only way I can run a query with the `format` method.

I have tried using `replace`, but cannot figure it out.

Comment: Do you want the *contents* of the string to contain both the double and single quotes?

Comment: Is the string value `'TEST'` or `TEST`? From the example it looks like it's a variable assignment and the string doesn't contain any quotes.

Comment: "_I have tried doing a .replace method_" Post that attempt here and explain what exactly was wrong with it.

Comment: `quoted = "'" + original + "'"`

Comment: `It is important the double quotes are around the single quotes` So you don't want to  _replace_ the single quotes so much as add double quotes whenever you see single quotes?

Comment: Use the builtin function `repr` https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr

Comment: Not sure why the answers are being upvoted. Until OP clarifies the question, they could be completely wrong. Especially since OP specified that: *"important the double quotes are around the single quotes"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outer quotes in a string literal are not part of the string, they *indicate* that you have a string object.

By going from `'TEST'` to `"'TEST'"` you are not replacing anything. You are adding two single quotes to a string of length 4!

```
>>> t1 = 'TEST'
>>> t2 = "'TEST'"
>>> len(t1)
4
>>> len(t2)
6
```

That being said, you can use `repr` to get the second string as desired.

```
>>> repr(t1)
"'TEST'"
```

This is a quick hack (see comments), it's more robust and explicit to use

```
"'{}'".format(t1)
```

Comment: @Hana no problem!

Comment: @Hana What "worked"? I don't see anything in the post that suggests you actually change anything in your code. If you used `repr` actually *in* your code, that is heavily discouraged, as there are typically not strong guarantees about its output across versions.

Comment: @jpmc26 If I had to guess, OP means that the queries work now by wrapping the strings in quotes.

Comment: I don't know because your answer doesn't seem to suggest doing that. I'm worried they dropped `repr` into their code.

Comment: @jpmc26 I'm afraid I don't follow. `some_string = repr(some_string)` will wrap `some_string` in extra quotes.

Comment: @timgeb [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr): "Return a string containing a printable representation of an object." This function exists primarily for debugging purposes, giving a representation that allows you to see the value. For strings, it doesn't *always* wrap stuff in double quotes. Try `repr('"test"')`, which gives back `'\'"test"\''`. Its behavior depends on the content, and it might escape some characters. For non-strings, it spits out whatever its defined to. String manipulation should be more explicit than that in code.

Comment: @jpmc26 And the context here is that OP has strings which are not wrapped in quotes, which they want to wrap in single quotes.

Comment: Do they? I don't see any particular specification about what strings they need to support. They just say "like this," but the details are never specified. For all I know, they mean they have incoming strings from a web request that have single quotes around them. It seems like even the OP isn't entirely clear on what data they have, to be honest.

Comment: @jpmc26 OK, you convinced me that I should at least add a clarification to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

There is no quotation mark to replace: the value of `char` is `TEST`, four characters.  The single quotation marks are Python syntax to indicate the data type.

If you want `char` to contain those single quotes, you can concatenate them to the original value:

```
char = "'" + char + "'"
```

The single quotes are contained in double quotes, per Python syntax.  You can also "escape" the characters:

```
char = '\'' + char + '\''
```

The backslash indicates that the follow character is to be interpreted as a literal character, not as a syntax indication.

Answer (score 1):

The single/double quote is used to declare a string type, both are usable, but they are not part of the string itself. However, if you want to have `'` in your string, use the double quote or vice versa.

```
char = 'TEST'
s = "'{}'".format(char)
print(s)
>>'TEST'
```

Answer (score 1):

The singles quotes **aren't part of the string**,  which contains only **4** characters,  `TEST`

For `py3`:

```
char = "TEST"
char = f"'{char}'"
```

For `py2`:

```
char = "TEST"
char = "'{}'".format(char)
```